# Run an event referring to an external web page ..?

Tags: java, php, jquery, asp.net, pdf

I ask you how to run an event related to an external web page.

In this case the external web page is the following: https://tools.pdf24.org/en/webpage-to-pdf

The web page converts the URL of web pages to pdf.

I want to programmatically execute the generation of PDF, considering that I have a list of web page that I need to be in PDF.

I ask if you have a tool in PHP, JQUERY or JAVA.

Where you can execute the generation of PDF by means of the external web page.

Thanks

Comment: please dont tag a question with every language

Comment: @nogad he *does* say he wants a solution in either languages. I agree though, he isn't *specific* at *all*.

Comment: what would be accepted if you got 4 answers each answering  for a different language. kind of breaks how S.O works

Comment: @nogad Yes I do agree, that is why I upvoted your comment aswell.

Comment: What you have to do is place the URL, run the "Convert to PDF" button and download the pdf file.

Answer (score -1):

At the time of this writing there are a couple of options, wkhtmltopdf and jsPDF.

wkhtmltopdf is a commandline line tool that uses the webkit engine to create PDFs from an HTML source.  There are also multiple server side libraries and wrappers for this that you can use.
(link at time of writing) https://wkhtmltopdf.org/

jsPDF is a client side library that accomplishes what you're asking.
(link at time of writing) https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF

Comment: Don't post link *only* answers, links can start being removed after a while. Thus, your answer isn't time proof. Try to explain your answer on here what the user mostly needs. I understand it's hard in this kind of questioning, but still... (I'm not downvoter, but could be reason of downvote).

Comment: What you have to do is place the URL, run the "Convert to PDF" button and download the pdf file.